# mySql query to find records not present in another table

Tags: mysql

I had two mySql tables of `CARS` and `DRIVERS` with the attribute `licenseNumber`
as a foreign key.

What would be the query to find the names of the drivers who did not have a car?

I was thinking:

```
SELECT DISTINCT D.name
FROM drivers D, cars C
WHERE 
 D.licenseNumber = C.licenseNumber AND 
  D.licenseNumber NOT IN (SELECT licenseNumber FROM cars)
```

But that doesn't return anything.
I have a feeling I'm overthinking it a bit.
Any help?

Comment: You're going to kick yourself when you realize what you did wrong. :-)

Comment: liceense number is primary key for CARS and foreign key for DRIVERS? Then your question is not possible. If no car means no primary key for cars,No foreign key possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT D.name 
FROM drivers D
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM cars c 
                 WHERE D.licenseNumber = C.licenseNumber)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works and seems like the most obvious solution.  Can't believe I didn't think of it!

Comment: This query has to do a separate sub-query for every 'Driver'. I know MySQL can do some powerful optimizations but I don't think they stretch this far. Apart from performance downsides, I also think this solution is too exotic for such a common SQL 'problem'.

Comment: PS: If you really don't like joins, and want to solve this with subqueries, look at Don Grossman's solution.

Comment: @Jochem - Sorry if you think this solution is exotic you need to get out more! It's a pretty standard solution to this problem. In SQL Server it is more efficient than `OUTER JOIN`. [relative performance varies in MySQL dependant on whether the column is Nullable or not.](http://explainextended.com/2010/05/27/left-join-is-null-vs-not-in-vs-not-exists-nullable-columns/)

Comment: Whilst writing I was thinking 'what if I am wrong?', but I decided to write down my thoughts anyway, realizing that if I in fact were wrong, someone would probably correct me and I would learn something from it. Well, there we go, 11 minutes later :-D Tnx!

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible for any row to match that query (if licenseNumber was not in the cars table, how would cars.licenseNumber = drivers.licenseNumber?).

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM drivers WHERE licenseNumber NOT IN (SELECT licenseNumber FROM cars)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT DISTINCT D.name
    FROM drivers D
    LEFT JOIN cars C ON D.licenseNumber = C.licenseNumber 
    WHERE C.SOMECOLUMNTHATCANNOTBENULL IS NULL
```

Although you might just do

```
SELECT DISTINCT D.name FROM drivers D WHERE D.licenseNumber is NULL
```

But that totally depends on how you have structured your data!

[EDIT: LEFT JOIN works like this: it takes ALL rows from the left mentioned column - drivers in this case - and for each tries to match a car (using the condition after ON). If no car is found a row for that driver is returned anyway, the columns that normally should come from car, are set to NULL. (If multiple cars are found for a single driver, multiple rows are returned).]

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT DISTINCT D.name, c.id

FROM drivers D LEFT JOIN  cars C

ON D.licenseNumber = C.licenseNumber WHERE c.id IS NULL`

I added the car id so i can find what driver does not have a car (c.id is null)